# Json schema precedence with multiple patternProperties

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm writing a schema that has multiple `patternProperties` elements. Is there a way to specify the precedence these patterns should be checked?

Given this schema:

```json
{
  $id: "https://example.com/mySchema",
  type: "object",
  patternProperties: {
    "^foo\\.bar\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.(?:string|boolean|date|)$": { // #1
      type: "object",
      properties: { ... }
    },
    "^bar\\.foo\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.(?:string|boolean|date|)$": { // #2
      type: "object",
      properties: { ... }
    },
    "^foo\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.(?:string|boolean|date|)$": { // #3
      type: "object",
      properties: { ... }
    },
  }
}
```

And the json being validated:

```json
{
  foo.bar.baz.boolean: { ... }
}
```

The validation is failing because it is checking against pattern `#3` instead of pattern `#1`. Is it possible to validate using the most restrictive pattern first?

For more context: I'm currently using AJV for implementing the validation. If there's a better alternative, I'm open the suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification doesn't indicate an order in which the patterns should be applied, so an implementation could do anything, from running them in sorted alphabetical order or any other ordering of its choosing.

However, **all** patterns that match each property must evaluate their subschemas, so the ordering that they are checked should not be significant. If you are finding that the implementation stops matching a particular property as soon as a matching pattern is found, that would be a bug that should be fixed.